# How to handle a blog post content in Angular?

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, rest, blogs

I'm implementing an Angular app with Laravel REST API as the backend. I want the app to have a feature of a microblog. I am planning to store formatted text with html tags (like <ul> or <b>) as TEXT field (MySQL database)

Let's say I'm sending a blog post of 64 000 characters to my Angular frontend. Can I assign that data to a variable of type string? I couldn't find information on what's the max length of a string in typescript.

Or maybe I am planning that functionality wrong and it should be done differently?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description

Comment: you'd probably want to gzip it at the server before sending it